# Client side + Server side templating, feels wrong to me, how to optimize?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, templating, handlebars.js

In the web app I am making, I use the classical Express+Jade to render client pages and also expose some REST API (let's say : "user list API").

These client pages use provided API to retrieve "user list" and display it. To display it, I use the handlebars template library once the data is retrieved.

It seems a bit dirty to me, using two template engines, parsing the code twice, how to make it better ?

Note : I already optimized the thing by sending the initial data within the client page by inserting it a script variable. This variable is then displayed the same way data received by API would be. The API is only used in case of data refresh.

**UPDATE :** using jade both server and client side is a good idea but how to seperate / specify ? Wich part of the rendered template should be done by when serving the page and what part will be used by the client ?

Comment: You can use Jade templates [in the browser](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a4). There are many other template engines which work both in Node and the browser, as well.

Comment: I know jade can be used both client and server side but how to separate client and server side template in the file ? How do you tell  server side Jade processor not to compute the client part of the template ?

Comment: I can't tell you how to organize your templates, the way I solve it is to keep the templates simple when I can, and use the same template on server and client. The layout only ever gets rendered on the server, while partials (resource templates) can get rendered where it makes sense.

Comment: Partials may be a good solution to the problem. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very easy to use Client side + Server side templating.When we are building some web apps,we should use ajax to get some data and use the callback function to deal with it.So we should render these data on the client side.

The question is how to render them on client side?

Now We just need a client side jade.js.

Follow this document :  https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

**First**

```
git clone https://github.com/visionmedia/jade.git
```

**Second**

```
$ make jade.js ( in fact the project has already compile the file for us )

so we just need to copy this file to the path that we use.
```

**Third**

```
read my demo below :

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src="lib/jade/jade.js"></script>
<script type='template' id='test'>
ul
  li hello world 
  li #{item}
  li #{item}
  li #{item}
</script>
<script>
  var compileText = $("#test").text();
  console.log( typeof( compileText ) );
  var fn = jade.compile( compileText , { layout : false } );
  var out = fn( {item : "this is item " } );
  console.log( out );
  $("body").append( out );
</script>
```

Now you can see the output result in the body

```
hello world
this is item
this is item
this is item
```

After reading this demo I think that you would know how to seperate jade server side and client side.If you can understand which one compile the jade template,then all the questions are easy.

Maybe you would have another question now.How to write some jade template codes in *.jade?The document also provide us a way to do it.This Tutorial may help you.

index.jade

```
!!!5
html
  head
   title hello world
  body
    ul#list

    script#list-template(type='template')
      |- for( var i in data )
      |    li(class='list') \#{ data[i].name }
      |- }
```

index.js

```
/* you javascript code */
var compileText = $('#list-template').text();
var compile = jade.compile( compileText , { layout : false } );

var data = [{ "name" : "Ben" } , {"name" : "Jack" } , {"name" : "Rose" }];
var outputText = compile( data );

$("#list").append( outputText );
```

Comment: I should have though about the script tag with a 'text/template' type. This answer is actually a bit better than my auto-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://github.com/flatiron/plates template engine which will work both on the client side and server side.

Comment: Plates seems uneasy to combine with express and I don't want to rewrite my app on flatrion (rewriting is the problem, not flatiron).

Comment: You could write the plugin for plates in express to imitate jade. Then it wouldn't be a big problem to combine with express

Comment: Yes but it wouldn't solve my question anyway, I would have the same problem as having jade for both client and server side : how to make a clean separation of client and server templates ?

Comment: I'll try to make a lib or something about that, I already found how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I did it. It's was quiet simple but I don't like the lack of logic. Here is [the github](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/express-plates) and here is the [npm registery link](http://search.npmjs.org/#/express-plates)

Comment: it works but the lack of logic in Plates is not compatible with my app without huge rewriting. Not the best solution. You deserve my upvote though ;)

Answer (score 1):

A few weeks ago I wrote an npm package for Handlebars templates to share them between client and server.  It's pretty basic, but it's been working really well for me so far:

https://github.com/jwietelmann/node-handlebars-precompiler

**Edit**: I'm separately using "hbs" as the package for server-side rendering. The precompiler just delivers precompiled templates to my public javascripts directory whenever I update my hbs views.

Comment: Didn't notice your answer before, really interesting !